# PostgreSQL цикл FOR

Tags: sql, строки, postgresql, функции, циклы

В процессе написания функции для postgresql возникла проблема: необходимо формировать SQL запрос, и впоследствии "скармливать" его циклу `FOR`. А т.к. запрос формируется динамически (в зависимости от условий), то не придумал ничего лучше чем записывать его в переменную типа `text`. Цикл отказывается принимать строку в качестве SQL запроса. 
Образец:

```
DECLARE
    table_string RECORD;
    query_string text := '';
BEGIN

query_string := 'SELECT * FROM tablename';

-- проблемный цикл
FOR table_string IN query_string
LOOP
   -- какой-то код
END LOOP;
END;
```

Язык функции plpgsql.

> pgAdmin III : "Ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение "query_string")
>   LINE 10: FOR table_string IN query_string" (ссылается на table_string)

Как решить эту проблему?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/ecpg-dynamic

Answer (score 1):

*Это решение было предложено автором вопроса в его предыдущем сообщении.*

Решение оказалось гораздо проще:

```
FOR table_string IN EXECUTE query_string
```

Достаточно было добавить `EXECUTE` перед переменной, в которой "сидит" SQL-запрос.